# How to use Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, xss, antixsslibrary

All the material I've seen about using Sanitizer to help prevent XSS attacks uses Microsoft.Security.Application. But since .NET 4.5, most of the library is now included in System.Web.Security.AntiXss — but only *most* of it… for some reason it is missing Sanitizer.

So how do I get Sanitizer in my application? Do I have to download the AntiXss library into my application and use this? It seems wrong to be downloading a DLL which is pretty much identical to System.Web.Security.AntiXss. Is this my only option? I've heard there is also a sanitizer in ajaxcontroltoolkit but it is pretty heavy weight considering I only want the sanitizer class.

I know I could just use a regex, but reducing the input to just a-zA-Z0-9 seems overzealous, and I'm not entirely confident in creating a whitelist that I could be confident doesn't leave me open to attack, but also isn't too restrictive.

So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The AntiXssLibrary's (Microsoft.Security.Application) Sanitizer still zaps the inline CSS that my WYSIWYG editor implements.

As far as I can tell, this article is still relevant: [antixss-4-2-breaks-everything](https://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/)

However, in his SanitizeHtml, I commented out the CssEncode(a.Value) because it was breaking my inline style.

Comment: How did you sanitize the css?

Comment: @AnotherDeveloper Fortunately, we're using the WYSIWYG editor for very basic formatting and not allowing the editing of the HTML.  I'm going with replacing key characters/strings to throw a wrench in a XSS attempt.  
`a.Value = a.Value.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace("javascript:", string.Empty);`   
`a.Value = Regex.Replace(a.Value, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);`  
[XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)
It looks like an effective XSS in style attributes needs parentheses and/or unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks jaybro. I have been using the TinyMCe Wysiwyg and so far so good.